# Bootstrap table data was displayed but any event occur goes to the table is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/ajaxapi/caselistmethod",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                $(".openCasesCount").text(this.TotalCount);
                $("#TotalRowsCount").val(this.TotalCount);
                $($($("#eventsTable").children('tbody')[0]).children('tr')[index]).append(
                               "<td>" + value.Id + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + value.Owner + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + this.ReferredUser + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + this.PhaseNumber + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + this.LocationOne + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + this.LocationTwo + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + this.Status + "</td>" +
                               "<td>" + this.LockedBy + "</td>");
            });
            $("#eventsTable").attr("data-total-rows", $("#TotalRowsCount").val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question, tell us what you want? what is not working?

Comment: initially displayed data in the table but any button click such as(sort) clear all data in the table.